# Flutter - calendar events

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, calendar, table-calendar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9dwl.png)
as you see in the image that the events are in days 1-5-2022 and 17-5-2022
but they are both loading in the two days,
I think the problem in the api method "getMeetApiEvents" but not sure

```
 List<Meet> _getMeetsFromDay(DateTime dateTime) {
    // final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    final String formatted = formatter.format(dateTime);
    DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.parse('$formatted 00:00:00.000');
    return selectedMeets[parsedDate] ?? [];
  }
```

this is the api method

```
  Future<Map<DateTime, List<Meet>>> getMeetApiEvents(
      {required BuildContext context}) async {
    
    Map<DateTime, List<Meet>> meetMap = {};
    List<Meet> meets = <Meet>[];
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var item = data.last;
if (item['error'] != "") {
        String s = await getError(errorText: item['error']);
        if (item['error'] != "2") {
          HDW().myAlertShow(context: context, error: s);
        }
        return {};
      } else {
        late DateTime parsedDate;
        for (var item in data) {
         parsedDate = DateTime.parse('${item['datenow']} 00:00:00.000');
         meets.add(
            Meet(
              id: item['id'],
              date: item['datenow'],
              owner: item['owner'],
              ),
            ),
          );
          Map<DateTime, List<Meet>> a = {
            // parsmeetMap.addEntries(a);edDate: [e],
            parsedDate: meets,
          };

          meetMap.addAll(a);
        }

      }
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("${response.statusCode} failed");
      }
      return {};
    }
    return meetMap;
  }
```

Comment: You have not provided the code to how you add meetings for date. Have you checked the selectedMeets object?

Comment: I add it to the post dear

Comment: I still don't see how selectedMeets gets populated...

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what method you want? what do you mean with "populated"